# Sticky nav bar with jQuery jerky on window resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, sticky

I'm working on a sticky nav-bar for the first time and I got everything working nicely until trying to make it responsive. When the window is resized, the jQuery for the nav bar causes the page to freeze for a bit feeling kind of jerky. Am I overdoing it with the resize checks?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //on page load will get nav offset and wrap nav in a placeholder 
    //for smooth transition to fixed position
    var navOffset = jQuery('.nav').offset().top;
    jQuery('.nav').wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery('.nav-placeholder').height(jQuery('.nav').outerHeight());

    //when window is resized will get new offset so nav 
    //goes sticky at right time
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    navOffset = jQuery('.nav').offset().top;
    jQuery('.nav').wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery('.nav-placeholder').height(jQuery('.nav').outerHeight());
    });



    //added some extra wraps for styling purposes mainly padding
    jQuery('.nav').wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"</div>');
    jQuery('.nav-inner').wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"</div>');

    //when scrolling past offset will set nav to fixed 'sticky'
    //when scrolling back up will unset the fixed sticky nav
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if(scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery('.nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your nav's height vary on different screen resolutions is that why you are wrapping it in a placeholder with javascript?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this comment earlier. Yes it does since my hero image width is set to cover, so height varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should limit the number of times the callbacks for events such as `resize`, `scroll` fire.

Common ways of achieving this is called throttle and debounce. Many javascript libraries such as underscore, lodash etc implement this.

In the case of jQuery, There is a jQuery plugin [jquery-throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)

You can use it like

```
jQuery(window).resize($.debounce( 250, function() {
  navOffset = jQuery('.nav').offset().top;
  jQuery('.nav').wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  jQuery('.nav-placeholder').height(jQuery('.nav').outerHeight());
}));
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great solution. I had a feeling I was overdoing it with the callbacks.