# How do I create a sticky nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, fixed, sticky

I am trying to make my nav bar stick to the top of the page as I scroll down the page. I have included a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qsy0Lwu/ I followed a w3schools example exactly, and it's not working. Please help.

In my research I have noticed a difference between offsetTop and offset().top. i have a feeling the problem has to do with something in my css.

I also noticed that the links in the navbar don't work when offsetTop is applied in the javascript. Although no errors show in the console. However, when I implement offset().top, an error shows in the console...but the nav bar links work

*HTML*

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="#">Apps</a> 
    <a href="#">TAB 1 </a> 
    <a href="#">TAB 2</a>
    <a href="#">TAB 3</a>
    <a href="#">TAB 4</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT  CONTENT 
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #161717;
margin-top: 0.1%;
text-align: center;
}

#navbar a {
display: inline-block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
 }

#navbar a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
 }

#navbar a.active {
background-color: #1e272d;
color: white;
 }

.container {
padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .container {
padding-top: 1000px;
}
```

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
 } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
 }
}

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky nav bar with jQuery jerky on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448051/sticky-nav-bar-with-jquery-jerky-on-window-resize)

Comment: If you just want it to be `position:sticky;` just do that from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use pure css with [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). To define how far from the top the value becomes sticky, modify the `top` property.

```
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

### Example 1

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red
}

nav>ul>li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

### Example 2

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 80vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red
}

nav>ul>li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to include jquery and the css is a bit off.

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4xLjuth/1/

I included jquery and updated the following to css:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red !important;
}

.sticky + .container {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Implement by using Intersection_Observer_API:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

**See a working example here:** https://jsfiddle.net/Hamzailyas434/1wz5g6L9/7/

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const navHeight = nav.getBoundingClientRect().height;
const stickyNav = function (entries) {
  const [entry] = entries;
  if (!entry.isIntersecting) nav.classList.add('sticky');
  else nav.classList.remove('sticky');
};
let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: `-${navHeight}px`,
};
const headerObserver = new IntersectionObserver(stickyNav, options);
headerObserver.observe(header);
```

```css
/* The page is NOT responsive. You can implement responsiveness yourself if you wanna have some fun  */

:root {
  --color-primary: #5ec576;
  --color-secondary: #ffcb03;
  --color-tertiary: #ff585f;
  --color-primary-darker: #4bbb7d;
  --color-secondary-darker: #ffbb00;
  --color-tertiary-darker: #fd424b;
  --color-primary-opacity: #5ec5763a;
  --color-secondary-opacity: #ffcd0331;
  --color-tertiary-opacity: #ff58602d;
  --gradient-primary: linear-gradient(to top left, #39b385, #9be15d);
  --gradient-secondary: linear-gradient(to top left, #ffb003, #ffcb03);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.9;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

/* GENERAL ELEMENTS */
.section {
  padding: 15rem 3rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;

  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.section--hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(8rem);
}

.section__title {
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto 8rem auto;
}

.section__description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--color-primary);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.section__header {
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: none;
  padding: 1.25rem 4.5rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-primary-darker);
}

.btn--text {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--color-primary);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

p {
  color: #666;
}

/* This is BAD for accessibility! Don't do in the real world! */
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

img {
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}

.lazy-img {
  filter: blur(20px);
}

/* NAVIGATION */
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 9rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 6rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* nav and stickly class at the same time */
.nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}

.nav__logo {
  height: 4.5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.nav__links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__item {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.nav__link:link,
.nav__link:visited {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.nav__link--btn:link,
.nav__link--btn:visited {
  padding: 0.8rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  color: #222;
}

.nav__link--btn:hover,
.nav__link--btn:active {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-darker);
  color: #333;
}

/* HEADER */
.header {
  padding: 0 3rem;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__title {
  flex: 1;

  max-width: 115rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  row-gap: 3rem;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

  align-items: start;
  justify-items: start;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header__img {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  transform: translateY(-6rem);
}

.highlight {
  position: relative;
}

.highlight::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1.07, 1.05) skewX(-15deg);
  background-image: var(--gradient-primary);
}

/* FEATURES */
.features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 4rem;
  margin: 0 12rem;
}

.features__img {
  width: 100%;
}

.features__feature {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.features__icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-opacity);
  height: 5.5rem;
  width: 5.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.features__icon svg {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  fill: var(--color-primary);
}

.features__header {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Bankist | When Banking meets Minimalist</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="nav">
        <img
          src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
          alt="Bankist logo"
          class="nav__logo"
          id="logo"
          designer="Hamza"
          data-version-number="3.0"
        />
        <ul class="nav__links">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#section--1">Features</a>
            <!-- <a class="nav__link" href="#section--1">Features</a> -->
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#section--2">Operations</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#section--3">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal" href="#"
              >Open account</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="header__title">
        <h1>
          When
          <!-- Green highlight effect -->
          <span class="highlight">banking</span>
          meets<br />
          <span class="highlight">minimalist</span>
        </h1>
        <h4>A simpler banking experience for a simpler life.</h4>
        <button class="btn--text btn--scroll-to">Learn more &DownArrow;</button>
        <img
          src="img/hero.png"
          class="header__img"
          alt="Minimalist bank items"
        />
      </div>
    </header>

    <section class="section" id="section--1">
      <div class="section__title">
        <h2 class="section__description">Features</h2>
        <h3 class="section__header">
          Everything you need in a modern bank and more.
        </h3>
      </div>

      <div class="features">
        <img
          src="img/digital-lazy.jpg"
          data-src="img/digital.jpg"
          alt="Computer"
          class="features__img lazy-img"
        />
        <div class="features__feature">
          <div class="features__icon">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="img/icons.svg#icon-monitor"></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <h5 class="features__header">100% digital bank</h5>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde alias
            sint quos? Accusantium a fugiat porro reiciendis saepe quibusdam
            debitis ducimus.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="features__feature">
          <div class="features__icon">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="img/icons.svg#icon-trending-up"></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <h5 class="features__header">Watch your money grow</h5>
          <p>
            Nesciunt quos autem dolorum voluptates cum dolores dicta fuga
            inventore ab? Nulla incidunt eius numquam sequi iste pariatur
            quibusdam!
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          src="img/grow-lazy.jpg"
          data-src="img/grow.jpg"
          alt="Plant"
          class="features__img lazy-img"
        />

        <img
          src="img/card-lazy.jpg"
          data-src="img/card.jpg"
          alt="Credit card"
          class="features__img lazy-img"
        />
        <div class="features__feature">
          <div class="features__icon">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="img/icons.svg#icon-credit-card"></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <h5 class="features__header">Free debit card included</h5>
          <p>
            Quasi, fugit in cumque cupiditate reprehenderit debitis animi enim
            eveniet consequatur odit quam quos possimus assumenda dicta fuga
            inventore ab.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>



    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```